# When navigating to a router via an alias, how to change the URL to the path?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When the user navigates to a page using an alias of the route, the URL stays with the alias and the page is rendered correctly.

How could I change to URL to the `path` when the user navigates to an alias?

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    alias: "*",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "NotFound" */ "@/views/NotFound.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    alias: "/home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/downloads",
    name: "Downloads",
    alias: ['/download', '/releases'], 
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Downloads" */ "@/views/Downloads.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

For example:

1. User types `www.example.com/home`.
2. Browser loads the `Home` page page.
3. URL gets changed to 'www.example.com/'.

Other:

1. User types `www.example.com/lalallaa`.
2. Browser loads the `NotFound` page page.
3. URL gets changed to 'www.example.com/404'.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I can only think about using the `created()` event on each page and manually setting the URL, but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want are [*redirects*](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect), not aliases.

Set up the known redirects you want like

- `/home` => `/`
- `/download` and `/releases` => `/downloads`

and then add a catch-all redirect to `/404` at the end of the `routes` array.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/404',
    component: { template: `<h1>404</h1>` }
  }, {
    path: '/',
    component: { template: `<h1>Home</h1>` }
  }, {
    path: '/home', redirect: '/'
  }, {
    path: '/downloads',
    component: { template: `<h1>Downloads</h1>` }
  }, {
    path: '/download', redirect: '/downloads'
  }, {
    path: '/releases', redirect: '/downloads'
  }, {
    path: '*', redirect: '/404'
  }]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.1.6/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li><router-link to="/home">/home</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/">/</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/downloads">/downloads</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/download">/download</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/releases">/releases</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/lalallaa">/lalallaa</router-link></li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <pre>$route.fullPath = {{ $route.fullPath }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing that after reading your comment. I just added the catch-all redirect right bellow the `/404` route. I'm going to move it down to the last position.

Comment: @NickeManarin yep, the ordering of your routes is significant. The idea is to go from most specific to least. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route